# celery task unable to iterate over multiple rows from postgresql database with python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, celery, fastapi, task-queue

I am using the `databases` python package (https://pypi.org/project/databases/) to manage connection to my postgresql database

from the documentation (https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/#queries)
it says i can either use

```
# Fetch multiple rows without loading them all into memory at once
query = notes.select()
async for row in database.iterate(query=query):
    ...
```

or

```
# Fetch multiple rows
query = notes.select()
rows = await database.fetch_all(query=query)
```

**Here is what i have tried:**

```
def check_all_orders():
    query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipped=True"
    return database.fetch_all(query)

...
...
...

@app.task
async def check_orders():

    query = await check_all_orders()
    
    today = datetime.utcnow()

    for q in query:
        if q.last_notification is not None:
            if (today - q.last_notification).total_seconds() < q.cooldown:
                continue
```

and

```
@app.task
async def check_orders():

    query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipped=True"

    today = datetime.utcnow()

    async for q in database.iterate(query=query):
        if q.last_notification is not None:
            if (today - q.last_notification).total_seconds() < q.cooldown:
                continue
```

**i have used both** but getting the following error:

> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
> kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable

full error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 472, in trace_task
    mark_as_done(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 154, in mark_as_done
    self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 434, in store_result
    self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 856, in _store_result
    self._set_with_state(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta), state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 324, in encode
    _, _, payload = self._encode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 328, in _encode
    return dumps(data, serializer=self.serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 53, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 21, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 49, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 65, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 55, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

The Schema.jsonify method--like jsonify from Flask--returns a Response object which kombu won't be able to serialize (IIRC kombu serializes to JSON by default). You should probably use dump instead of jsonify to return a dictionary.

Comment: this is not flask..using fastapi...but is there a generic way to solve this that is framework agnostic? also a not using jsonify, so not sure why you said `instead of using jsonify`

Comment: i just tried `json.dumps(query)` to serialize the query result and still getting same error...you mind sharing how how to use json dumps from above code?