# What is the sql query equivalent to sqlalchemy query?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, celery, fastapi

I am having issues ietrating over results from SQL query with using encode databases (https://pypi.org/project/databases/)
but this sqlalchemy query works fine for the celery tasks

```
query = session.query(orders).filter(orders.shipped == True)
```

I have tried the following ([celery task unable to iterate over multiple rows from postgresql database with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507520)) but does not work

```
def check_all_orders():
    query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipped=True"
    return database.fetch_all(query)

...
...
...

@app.task
async def check_orders():

    query = await check_all_orders()
    
    today = datetime.utcnow()

    for q in query:
        if q.last_notification is not None:
            if (today - q.last_notification).total_seconds() < q.cooldown:
                continue
```

Does anyone know what SQL statement will generate what i can iterate like it does for this sqlalchemy query?

```
query = session.query(orders).filter(orders.shipped == True)
```

Comment: Celery is not yet capable of dealing with async functions. Why? - It predates them! It has own way of doing asynchronous execution.

Comment: i see..but i still need help though; can you help with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy's resulting query depends on what particular backend engine you use. For example, `filter(orders.shipped == True)` can be converted to something like `WHERE shipped = 't'` for PostgreSQL. You can always [log the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950685/168352) it sends to database backend. For your particular case `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipped` should be enough.

Comment: issue is celery tasks doesnt work for me...it works for the sqlalchemy query but not for the databases package am using with raw sql statement..check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507520

so what am trying to do now is to be able to get same result as sqlalchemy and then am good, if result is same..am using https://pypi.org/project/databases/